# How to mark an email as Junk/Spam in EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, exchange-server-2007

I am developing an email client using EWS. I know there is a XML tag [MarkAsJunk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj219965(v=exchg.150).aspx) to mark an email as Junk. But this tag is only available for Exchange version 2013 or later. What is the way to mark an email as Junk/Spam in Exchange version less than 2013 ??. Does move an email to Junk Email folder will ban future emails coming from that sender ??